# Pre_process a column of tweets and make a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

I have a CSV file that includes 2319 tweets and their labels. I read it in a dataframe and it looks like the following:
[image]
I want to read each tweet and do the following:

Remove stopwords, Remove links, Remove # , Remove punctuations, Remove @(mentions), lowercasing, Tokenization, Also remove emojies

And then store each processed tweet in a new column of data frame(Lets say Processed Text). Therefore the previous dataframe will be changed to something like following:(following table would be my desired output in dataframe)
[image]

I wrote the following code in Jupyter:

```
from io import StringIO
df['Processed Text']= df['Text']
col = ['Text','Processed Text','Label']
df = df[col]

# remove missing values in “Text” column
import re
df = df[pd.notnull(df['Text'])]
for tweet in df['Processed Text']:
    print(tweet)
df['Processed Text'] = df['Processed Text'].apply(lambda x: re.split('https:\/\/.*', str(x))[0])
import string 
def remove_punctuations(text):
    for punctuation in string.punctuation:
        text = text.replace(punctuation, '')
    return text
df["Processed Text"] = df['Processed Text'].apply(remove_punctuations)
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
ls=[]
for tweet in df['Processed Text']:
    tweet = tweet.lower() # convert text to lower-case
    tweet = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))', 'URL', tweet) # remove URLs
    tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', tweet) # remove usernames
    tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet) # remove the # in #hashtag
    tweet = word_tokenize(tweet) # remove repeated characters (helloooooooo into hello)
    ls.append(tweet)
```

But I have two problems:
first: after running my code, I see still there are stopwords and punctuations. this code creates a list of lists, not dataframe. I need my output in a dataframe with 3 columns: Text, label, Processed Text

Comment: Looks like you already have a column of 'processed text' in the data frame. what is your question?

Comment: @Sonia I have edited my question. now it is clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To remove the stopwords, you can use stopwords list from nltk as below.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
STOP_WORDS = stopwords.words('english')
len(STOP_WORDS) # 179

for i in df['Processed Text']:
   sents = []
   for j in i:
      k = j.split(' ')
      k = [i.lower() for i in k]
      k = [i for i in k if i not in STOP_WORDS] 
      sents.append(' '.join(k))
   x = " ".join(sents)
```

You can append more stop words specific to your project to the STOP_WORDS list and create your own customized STOP_WORDS.

For addressing the punctuations, your code looks good. string punctuation removes !"#$%&'()*+, -./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~
if you have additional punctuations, create a custom list for punctuations like the STOP_WORDS list above and add the escaping punctuations to it. Are the punctuations in the list above show up again in your preprocessed text?

Regarding the list of lists, while you append use join as shown in the code above so the list becomes a sentence/phrase. Then assign the list to a variable/column name. For eg.,

```
ls.append(" ".join(tweet))
```